# Add a class or id to an item in object in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Actually not sure how to explain this properly but here goes...

In my script I output a list of athletes from an array of objects.

the image below shows the output...

[image: Add Athlete]

I added the bin icon with the intention of allowing users to delete  the record.
In my object I have a key trash -and I set

`const del = data.trash = ''`

In my loop to print the results I use:

`ID: ${i+1} - ${res[i].firstName}, ${res[i].lastName}, Age: ${res[i].age}, Club: ${res[i].club}, EaNumber: ${res[i].eanum}, ${del}`

The question is that I would like to make the icon functional - I tried adding `<span id='my-id'>` in the output and then creating an event listener -but that did not work. Does any one know of a method of a method of achieving this either in the loop or in the object?

Hope I explained myself properly.

Comment: Could you provide some codes for us to start with a working example? It is hard to achieve what you want without a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I do something like this, I would do:

```js
let ath = ['Foo Bar', 'Baz Qux']
let nid = 0;

for (let a of ath) {
  document.getElementById('alc').innerHTML += `<li id="alc-${nid++}"><span class="n">Loading...</span> <button onclick="del(${nid - 1})">Del</span></li>`;
  document.querySelector(`#alc #alc-${nid - 1} .n`).innerText = a;
}

function del(id) {
  ath.splice(id, 1);
  document.getElementById(`alc-${id}`).remove();
}
```

```html
<p>This contains athletes:</p>
<ul id="alc"></ul>
```

Comment: Cool great help , thank you  all is working well - so thank you.